# How to query on a for loop in R

Tags: mysql, sql, r

I have a sql database that has two columns, one with person IDs and one with their info. I have a data frame of patient IDs that I wish to query from the sql database, I want to query them by using a for loop and I want the data that is obtained from the for loop to be transferred into a table, but have been unsuccessful.

I tried different variations of a for loop, but they all lead to errors of string vectors or they only put the most recent information in the table, omitting any other information of any ID before.

```
for (i in CancerMet2){
  x <- dbGetQuery(mydb, paste('SELECT * FROM kv WHERE Person = ', i, ';'))
  info = fromJSON(x$info)
  print(i)
}
```

Then I get this error:

> Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) :    Expecting a single
>   string value: [type=character; extent=90907].

The expected results should be a table with the people's ID's and corresponding info of the selected people IDs I have in a data frame.

Comment: From the Value section of `DBI::dbGetQuery`: *dbGetQuery() always returns a data.frame*. Apparently you do not need `fromJSON`.

Comment: the `paste()` syoud be a `paste0()`, isnt it?

Answer (score 1):

Consider DBI's `sqlInterpolate` to safely and efficiently bind parameter to query and avoid any need to concatenate or punctuate:

```
# PREPARED STATEMENT (NO DATA)
sql <- "SELECT * FROM kv WHERE Person = ?pid"

for (i in CancerMet2){ 
  query <- sqlInterpolate(conn, sql, pid = i)
  info <- dbGetQuery(conn, query)

  print(info)
}
```

To save results in a named list of data frames:

```
df_list <- setNames(lapply(CancerMet2, function(i) {
                             query <- sqlInterpolate(conn, sql, pid = i))
                             dbGetQuery(conn, query) 
                           }), 
                    paste0("Person_", CancerMet2))

df_list$Person_1
df_list$Person_2
df_list$Person_3
...
```

Comment: since the vector is longer than length 1 it brings out this error code: Error in vapply(values, function(x) { : values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 90907

Comment: Where is `vapply` used here? Vapply is usually for simplified structures (vector/matrix) not non-simplified (list/data frame).